# How to use memcache unique key for multiple queries

Tags: php, memcached

I am firing multiple queries in my php code:

Ex :

```
$query1 = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1);
$query2 = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1);
$query3 = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1);
```

I want memcache implementation for all queries. How can I achieve this using single unique key?

Comment: Using 3 different queries having the same sql statement devalues the purpose of memcache

Comment: @Dr.Dan : you mean I need to use different unique keys for different queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing memcache and sql.  Here are some problems I notice:

- You have sql statements as your parameters to these functions.  That is incorrect.  Memcache works on a key lookup scheme.
- The specific method fetchAll() takes no parameters.  Please look at the examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.fetchall.php)
- Keys cannot have spaces in memcache.  So either choose your keyspace to not have spaces, or run them through md5() right before you do a lookup or save.
- Why would you run the exact same query for three separate variables.  Are you expecting the three `$query` variables to be different?